# Theorem 3.54 Baby Rudin (Riemann's Series Theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf, conditional-convergence

I am struggling trying to understand the final part of the proof of Theorem 3.54 on Baby Rudin.
Here's the Theorem

> Let $\sum a_n$ be a conditionally convergent series. Suppose :
>   $$
> -\infty \leq \alpha\leq \beta \leq +\infty$$
>   Then there exist a rearrangement $\sum a'_n$ with partial sums $\{s'_n\}$ such that
>
> $$
> \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \inf s'_n=\alpha \quad \quad \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup s'_n=\beta$$

The complete proof can be seen here, in this question [Theorem 3.54 (about certain rearrangements of a conditionally convergent series) in Baby Rudin: A couple of questions about the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039695/theorem-3-54-about-certain-rearrangements-of-a-conditionally-convergent-series).
I didn't quite understand the last part, namely

> Finally, it is clear that no number less than $\alpha$ or greater than $\beta$ can be a subsequential limit of the partial sums of (25).

How do i prove this statement exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the series is convergent $a_n\to 0$, thus if $\epsilon >0$ then there is an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, 
$$|a_n|<\epsilon$$ this implies that 
For all $n\geq N$,
$$\alpha-\epsilon<s_n<\beta+\epsilon$$
This is the construction, once one gets bigger that $\beta$ or less that $\alpha$, one turns around and goes the other way.